# problem of adding the range_sensor_layer to costmap_2D plugins

Tags: navigation, move-base, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am a fresh man to ROS system.I bulid a robot platfom use ros. i use move_base in my systerm.
I have a laser scan and some ultrasonic sensors in my systerm,but for using the ultrasonic sensor i got some problem.
i dont konw how to add the range_sensor_layer as a costmap plugins.
i tried just add

In costmap_common_params.yaml
add the layer of ultrasonic

```
 ultrasonic_layer:  
 enabled: true  
 max_obstacle_height: 0.4  
 origin_z: 0.0  
 z_resolution: 0.2  
 z_voxels: 2  
 unknown_threshold: 15  
 mark_threshold: 0  
 combination_method: 1  
 track_unknown_space: true #true needed for disabling globalpath planning through unknown space  
 obstacle_range: 1.0  
 raytrace_range: 3.0  
 publish_voxel_map: false  
 observation_sources: ultrasonic  
 ultrasonic:  
  data_type: Range  
  topic: ultrasonic  
  marking: true  
  clearing: true
```

In local_costmap_params.yaml like

```
plugins:  
  - {name: obstacle_layer, type: "costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"}  
  - {name: ultrasonic,   type: "range_sensor_layer::RangeSensorLayer"}  
  - {name: inflation_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
```

but when i run the move base i got some error said: "range_sensor_layer::RangeSensorLayer" is not surported by the plugin .

i can get the range informations using : `$rostopic echo ultrasonic`

did i missed something? or did i do somrthing wrong?
and can anybody tell me the correct way to use the range_sensor_layer as a plugin?

thanks a lot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241495/problem-of-adding-the-range_sensor_layer-to-costmap_2d-plugins/) by [zink](https://answers.ros.org/users/27719/zink/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-08-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2016-08-21**:
Can you please post the actual error message that you got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My guess is your issue stems from how you defined your ultrasonic plugin. Try the following instead:

```
ultrasonic:
    topics: ["/ultrasonic"]
    no_readings_timeout: 1.0
    clear_on_max_reading: true
```

Then also remove all of your "ultrasonic_layer:" definition to prevent confusion (Unless you are using that plugin elsewhere). You only need to define a layer/plugin once.

Also the RangeSensorLayer has no 'marking' or 'clearing' parameters (unlike ObstacleLayer) so you don't need those lines.

Let us know if this fixes your problem.

---

Originally posted by [biglotusturtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/30307/biglotusturtle/) with karma: 165 on 2017-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0